# XML in _POST variable not converting to XML when using PHP's simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have this PHP script that is catching a variable from this partner of ours. In the variable is a string of XML. When they process the file, it keeps giving errors like this :

> Warning:
>   SimpleXMLElement::__construct() :
>   Entity: line 19: parser error :
>   Premature end of data in tag
>   description line 19 in... then
>   lists the script path.

Here is a sample of the data that is being passed :

```
xml=<Posting>
<description><![CDATA[<p>this is a test posting.</p>

Here is some more of the test.]]></description>
</Posting>
```

I set up a test file that contained a textarea with that same code as shown above and named xml. When I submit it, the script works fine and finishes just as it should. The partner's log starts out as 'HTTP raw request is POST'. Not sure if this is somehow different but the more details the better I suppose. I have tried this on a separate servers as well but all of my test work when I am sending the data but not when the partner sends it.

Here is how I am catching the data :

```
if ($_POST['xml']) {
    $xmlstr = stripslashes($_POST['xml']);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only guess, but maybe the problem is with the newlines in your data. Have you tried to collapse the string to one single line before processing it?

Comment: I can try that but how would that explain my tests working every time?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a difference in how magic_quotes_gpc() is configured on your different servers (phpinfo(); can tell you)? stripslashes() should only be required if that's there, if it's not it may end up breaking your XML.

Comment: That was added because when the partner was sending the data over, there were slashes before all of the quotes.